# Excel - select value from first and last row with value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

1. I have a worksheet (`sheet1`) in Excel, which contains list of workplaces, each workplace(`B1`) has a location (`L1`).
2. On another sheet(`sheet2`) I have a list of locations(`A1`) and next to it I need the name of the first workplace with that location in one column and last workplace with that location in a column next to it.

Example data on `sheet1`:

| workplace(`B1`) | Location(`L1`) |
| --- | --- |
| A1111 | loc1 |
| A1112 | loc1 |
| A1113 | loc1 |
| A1114 | loc1 |
| A1115 | loc1 |
| A1116 | loc1 |
| A1117 | loc1 |
| B1111 | loc2 |
| B1112 | loc2 |
| B1113 | loc2 |
| B1114 | loc2 |
| B1115 | loc2 |
| B1116 | loc2 |
| B1117 | loc2 |

Example data on `sheet2`:

| location(`A1`) | First workplace(`B1`) | Last workplace(`C1`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| loc1 |  |  |
| loc2 |  |  |

**What formula to use to select the First and last workplace with that location name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to extract the data.

- To extract the first workplace:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$16,MATCH($E3,$B$3:$B$16,0))
```

[image: Formula for first cell]

- To extract the last workplace:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$16,MATCH($E3,$B$3:$B$16,1))
```

[image: Formula for last cell]

Drag the formula down to fill the other cells. Adapt it to match your sheets, tables and ranges.